# Total Values of Rows having same value in specific column

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I want to total the value in the 3rd and 4th columns of rows having the same value in column 2.

My file looks something like the following:

```
18 1600012 0 8
18 1600014 0 3
18 1600014 0 4
18 1600014 0 5
18 1600015 0 5
18 1600015 4 4
```

and the desired output would be

```
18 1600012 0 8
18 1600014 0 12
18 1600015 4 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk like this:

```
awk '{k=$1 OFS $2; c3[k] += $3; c4[k] += $4} END{for (i in c3) print i, c3[i], c4[i]}' file
```

**Output:**

```
18 1600014 0 12
18 1600015 4 9
18 1600012 0 8
```

Comment: Works fantastically! I did pipe into a sort argument to regain the desired order

Comment: `awk '{k=$1 OFS $2; c3[k] += $3; c4[k] += $4} END{for (i in c3) print i, c3[i], c4[i]}' $f | sort -k2,2 -n `

Comment: If you have `gnu-awk` then `sort` is not needed by using: `awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"} {k=$1 OFS $2; c3[k] += $3; c4[k] += $4} END{for (i in c3) print i, c3[i], c4[i]}' f`